# Disabling TLS renegotiation in Python

Tags: python, ssl, cherrypy

I'm implementing SSL connection in my web.py however the server fails security scanning and stuck on TLS Renegotiation DoS vulnerability.

Here is my code snippet:

```
import web

from web.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer

CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate = "path/to/ssl_certificate"
CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_private_key = "path/to/ssl_private_key"

urls = ("/.*", "hello")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Is it any possible way to disable TLS Renegotiation in web.py? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Five years without an answer? I assume the APIs you've been using have changed by now. But since the title of the question refers to Python in general, I'll answer that.

Python 3.7 has a flag for disabling renegotiation, but it requires openssl 1.1.0 or later. For older Python versions, the trick seems to be to update the underlying openssl library.

For background, see the discussion in this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue32257